# Frozen frames warning Google Play pre launch report

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, google-play-console

I have developed an Android game using **Cocos2d-X** engine. The **pre-launch** report on Google Play shows following warning:

***Frozen frames 33.33% of the frames took longer than 700ms to render***

I have following questions:

1. Is this warning expected for **games** as they are built using **OpenGL**?
2. If no, how can I fix this warning? Should I check with the real devices if there are such issues?

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

1. No, this warning is not expected for games. Open GL should be capable of rendering much faster than this. To be clear, 700ms rendering for a frame implies less than 2 frames per second. OpenGL is capable of 10s of FPS on many devices.
2. There are lots of ways to investigate this.

   - You should definitely check with real devices. But know that the Pre-launch report runs with real devices. You might want to look at the report and see if the errors are worse on some devices than others. If the slow rendering happens across all devices it is easier to investigate.
   - There is [a whole article on testing UI performance](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/performance) on developers.android.com.
   - If you prefer videos, there are video tutorials from Google developers [like this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VzYkVL1n4M8)
   - In the android vitals documentation there is [a whole article on identifying UI jank](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render) (another way to describe slow rendering)